# How can I build from specific branch in Azure Devops?

Tags: git, build, azure-devops

I'm new to GIT but have used VSTS for a while.  I want to build/deploy from specific branches.  I read this:

*YAML PR triggers are only supported in GitHuib and Bitbucket Cloud.  If you are using Azure Repos Git you can configure a branch policy for build validation in order to trigger your build pipeline for validation.*

I read about branch policies, but I am not seeing the connection.  All I want is to create a build pipeline for my develop branch and another one for my staging branch.  Can someone please explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using YAML builds or visual designer builds? And why do you want two separate builds? You can choose which branch to build when you queue it.

Comment: I want them to build automatically upon checkin to the specific builds, but we're using the free version so we are limited in build minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to use the develop and staging branches as target branches,then trigger the build when a pr merged from the source branch to the target branch is created ?

If so, first you need to set up **Build validation** in the branch policy of the develop/staging branch. Then select the build pipeline you want pr to trigger in the **Build pipeline** drop-down list of **Add build policy** dialog.

[image]

If you just want to build from specific branch,as Daniel said ,you only need to select which branch to run when running pipeline.

[image]

Comment: But when I do the latter, the "Run" button is disabled and I cannot run the pipeline against that branch. It is only enabled if I select the "master" branch. Any clue why?

Comment: It's probably because in the branch you have selected, the pipeline file does not exist. When this happens, Azure displays a scary message "Encountered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline YAML file for this branch/tag" above the Branch/tag field.

Or it could be because a required parameter or variable is not specified.